# How to retrieve uploaded file using ajax on java server side?

Tags: ajax, file-upload, struts2

I am using struts2 framework on server side. I am uploading a file using

server side :

```
<s:file name="fTU" id="fTU"/>

<input type="submit" value ="ok" onclick="upload()">
```

client side :

```
function upload(){

var file = document.getElementById("fTU");

try {
    this.xml = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e) {
    try {
        this.xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (err) {
        this.xml = null;
    }
}
if(!this.xml && typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined")
    this.xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
if (!this.xml){
    this.failed = true; 
}

var formData = new FormData();
/* Add the file */ 
formData.append("upload", file.files[0]);
```

xml.open("POST", "", true);
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "false");

```
xml.send(formData);  /* Send to server */

xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
        alert(xml.statusText);
    }
}
```

}

How to fetch the uploaded file object on struts2 server side?

It is going in server side class and I am trying to retrieve file by using request.getParameter(upload) but it is giving null.

Comment: To retrieve uploaded file you need to send it first.

Comment: Hi Roman, I am appending the file in formData and then formData is sent through XMLHttpRequest. Isn't it the correct way? Please let me know if there is anything wrong in the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed to add the Action Link in the `xml.open()` method. Take a look at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) to see some examples.

How does your `Action`-class look like? Have you defined a `File` field named **upload** with getter/setters?

Please also check, that your browser supports the `FormData` element, see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload).

I also would suggest you to use a library like jQuery to simplify the Javascript code.

**Action**

```
public class FileUpload extends ActionSupport {
   File myFile;

   public String execute() {
       //do some preparations for the upload
       return SUCCESS;
   }

   public String upload() {
       //only here the myFile is filled with data
       return SUCCESS;
   }

   public void setMyFile(File myFile) {
       this.myFile = myFile;
   }

   public File getMyFile() {
       return myFile;
   }
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<!-- init method to show the form -->
<action name="fileForm" class="...FileUpload">
    <result name="success">fileupload.jsp</result>
</action>

<!-- upload method to upload the file -->
<action name="fileUpload" class="...FileUpload" method="upload">
    <result name="success">fileupload.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**JSP**

```
<s:form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="fileinfo" action="fileUpload">
    <s:file name="myFile"/>
</s:form>

<input type="submit" onClick="upload()" value="OK">
```

**Javascript (taken from the MDN example above)**

```
function upload() {
   var fd = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));
   $.ajax({
       url : "fileUpload", //this is the actionName
       type: "POST",
       data: fd,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false
   });

   return false; //to stop submitting the form
}
```

I have not tested this code, so please change it or add comments if something doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks friend. I have made following changes in the upload function to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

```
function upload(form){
   var fd = new FormData(form);
   $.ajax({
       url : "<url-value>", //this is the actionName
       type: "POST",
       data: fd,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       success: function(data){
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```